# $f$ is measurable iff its restrictions are measurable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $X$ and $f$ an extended real-valued function on $X$. Show that $f$ is measurable if and only if its restrictions to $E$ and $X\setminus E$ are measurable.

Answer (score 2):

First, use the definition of measurability of functions to reduce the problem to showing that, for subsets $A$ of $X$, $A$ is measurable if and only if both $A\cap E$ and $A\setminus E$ are measurable.  (You'll need this for sets $A$ of the form $f^{-1}(B)$ for certain subsets $B$ of the extended real line.)  Then use that $E$ is measurable, that $A=(A\cap E)\cup(A\setminus E)$ and that measurable sets constitute a Boolean algebra of sets.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for the response.

How would you set that up?