# If a f's restriction to D is measurable and E~D is measurable, then f is measurable on E

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

Let f be an extended real-valued function on E. Let D be a measurable subset of E.

1. (i) If f is measurable on E and f = g a.e. on E, then g is measurable on E.
2. (ii) f is measurable on E if and only if it's restriction to D and E~D are measurable.

And I can do it, until I reach 2(ii) going "<-".

How should I go about it?
I found this answer: [$f$ is measurable iff its restrictions are measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330660/f-is-measurable-iff-its-restrictions-are-measurable) but the thing is he is only going in one direction and not the other.

I feel like the proof should be trivial because even Royden's skip over it, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Is $E$ equipped with a [complete measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure)? If so then that information must be mentioned in your question. If not then the first statement is not true.

Answer (score 3):

It's just that the union of any two measurable sets is always a measurable set. This is a part of the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra!

Given that the restriction of $f$ to $D$ and $E - D$ are measurable, we know, for any $a \in \mathbb R$, that $f^{-1}(a, \infty) \cap D$ and $f^{-1}(a , \infty) \cap (E - D)$ are both measurable sets. But $$f^{-1}(a,\infty) = (f^{-1}(a, \infty) \cap D) \cup (f^{-1}(a , \infty) \cap (E - D)),$$ so $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable too. Since $a$ is arbitrary, this proves that $f$ is a measurable function.

Comment: How do I know f−1(a,∞)∩(E−D)f−1(a,∞)∩(E−D)   is measurable?

Comment: Because if $f|_{E - D}$ denotes the restriction of $f$ to $E - D$, then $f^{-1}|_{E-D}(a, \infty) = f^{-1}(a, \infty)\cap (E - D)$. And since $f|_{E-D}$ is a measurable function, $f^{-1}|_{E-D}(a, \infty) $ is measurable.

Comment: oh, I got so confused. I thought the SET E~D is measurable not the restriction of the function to it! Thank you so much!

Comment: The set $E- D$ is also measurable as a consequence of the function being measurable when restricted to it, because $f^{-1}|_{E - D}(-\infty, \infty) = E-D$.

Comment: But what about the other side inclusion? How can we conclude that if f is measurable then it's restriction to a measurable subset is measurable?