For a measurable subset D of E, f is measurable on E if and only if the restrictions of f to D and E/D are measurable
I am reading through Royden's Real Analysis right now, and it uses the following fact and the fact that measurable sets are an algebra to prove this theorem without any explanation:
$\{x \in E | f(x) > c\} = \{x \in D | f(x) > c\} \cup \{x \in E \setminus D| f(x) > c\}$
I understand how the above equality and algebra makes the backwards direction apparent (if both sets on the right are measurable, then their union is measurable and therefore the left side of the equality is measurable).
However, I am struggling to understand the other direction. If we assume $\{x \in E | f(x) > c\}$ is measurable, what is it about an algebra of sets that guarantees the two sets $\{x \in D | f(x) > c\}$ and  $\{x \in E \setminus D| f(x) > c\}$ are measurable? I'm new to thinking of sets as an algebra, so perhaps there is a property I am missing?

Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330660/f-is-measurable-iff-its-restrictions-are-measurable

In fact,if $E=\bigcup\limits _{i=1}^{n}E_i$ and each $E_i$ is measurable,then f is measure iff the restrictions of $f$ to each $E_i$ is measurable.
Sufficiency: Let $f_i$ be $f|_{E_i}$,then for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$,$f_i^{-1}((c,+\infty])=f^{-1}((c,+\infty])\cap E_i$ is measurable.
Necessity: For all $c \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
f^{-1}((c,+\infty])
=&f^{-1}((c,+\infty])\cap E\\
=&f^{-1}((c,+\infty])\cap \bigcup\limits _{i=1}^{n}E_i\\
=&\bigcup\limits _{i=1}^{n} f^{-1}((c,+\infty])\cap E_i\\
=&\bigcup\limits _{i=1}^{n} f_i^{-1}((c,+\infty])
\end{align}
is measurable.

Thank you! I think this clears it up. I was completely missing that we can write $f_i^{-1} ((c, +\infty])$ as the intersection of two measurable sets (the preimage of f and the measurable set $E_i$). Therefore, from my equation above, we can just write ${x \in D|f(x) >c}$ as ${x \in E | f(x) > c} \cap D$ and measurability easily follows.
